# WSL + nginx медленно загружается проект

Tags: nginx, wsl

Разрабатываю проект yii2, операционка windows 10, в ней лежат все исходники.
Сервер nginx установлен в Ubuntu (работаю через WSL).

Проект загружается оооооооооочень медленно (секунд 30-40, хотя стартовая страница никаких данных из базы не тянет).

Пробовал такие решения:

1.
в файл /etc/nginx/nginx.conf добавить строку

```
http {
...
fastcgi_buffering off;
...
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////
2.

```
Edit /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf
comment out fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
and add fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

Edit /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
comment out listen = /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
and add listen = 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Не помогает.
Может кто сталкивался, как вышли из этой ситуации.

Comment: Попробуйте лучше в Docker, WSL это все таки не сам Linux а его кастрат

Comment: Я начинающий программист. Пришел на работу, мне сказали работай с этим, теперь борюсь.
С Докером тоже не работал, поизучаю.

Comment: @АндрейКоломоец `Я начинающий программист. Пришел на работу, мне сказали работай с этим, теперь борюсь.` - если вы начинающий программист, это не ваша проблема. Как это побороли коллеги? Или они работают не через WSL? Вы точно не должны бороться с такими вещами, это не программирование, а борьба с посторонними сложностями.

Comment: `fastcgi_buffering off;` вряд ли поможет, по сути это отключает буфферизацию последнего участка трубы PHP => Nginx => пользователь. А причина, я уверен, в начале. `and add listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` - вы по сути поменяли сокет на порт. И это я бы сказал даже медленнее. Но опять же, причина не в этом. Вы вряд ли решите эту проблему без помощи коллег. Надо пользоваться командой.

Comment: `хотя стартовая страница никаких данных из базы не тянет`. А вообще отпрофилируйте страницу. Для этого есть XHProf, Blackfire и другие инструменты. Возможно там есть сетевые запросы, например курл дергает курсы валют, либо обработка сессий (и внезапно они в БД лежат), или таски навешаны.